# When I call models from other app it doesn't show. In shell work

Tags: python, django

### I'm trying to call app models from a project views. In the app work but not in project.

### Project location

```
- SSS
  - gallery
     - models.py
     - views.py
     - apps.py
     - admin.py
  - sss
     - settings.py
     - views.py
     - urls.py
     - __init__.py
```

```
    from gallery.models import Gallery

    def homepage(request)

        galleries = Gallery.objects.all()

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'galleries': galleries})
```

---

### How I call in HTML

```
  {% for galleries in gallery %}
    <li class="diamond">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ gallery.images.url }}" alt="">
    </li>
  {%  endfor %}
```

> I tried sss.gallery.models import Gallery But the server said "no
>   module name sss.gallery". I tried gallery.models import Gallery In
>   Pycharm it has red underline under it.

But nothing Shown up. Please Help. Sorry for my English. I'm not good at describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with importing, or with apps. The variables in your for loop are the wrong way round. It should be:

```
{% for gallery in galleries %}
```

Comment: I don't understand what that means. What does the app have to do with anything?

Comment: like, it works in gallery.views directory. but not in sss.views directory. sorry for explained wrong.

Comment: I got it. sorry, and Thank you for your replies! In views I put return render(request, 'index.html', other_context , {'galleries': galleries}) so it didn't work!